# Correct way to think about a sigma algebra generated by a set

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $ X = \{1,2,3\}, C_1=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$,

$C_2=\{1,2\} \text{ and } \sigma(C) \text { is the smallest sigma algebra generated by } C, \text{then}$ 
$\sigma(C_1) = \{\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2\},\{3\},\{2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\},\phi \} $.

But how do I think about $\sigma(C_2)$?

$\{ \phi,X,\{3\},\{1,2\}\}$ sounds right to me as $1$ and $2$ are individual elements of that set. But if this is true then $\sigma(\{1\})=\{\phi,X,\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $\sigma(\{1\}) \not\subset \sigma(C_2), $ which is probably not true since $ \{1\} \subset \{1,2\} $.

Does it mean that $\sigma(C_2) $ is actually same as $\sigma-$ algebra generated by the set $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}   $.

This may sound like a silly question but I am really new to this kind of mathematics and just trying to make sure that I get my basics right. I will appreciate if you someone can let me know where I am flawed in my understanding.

Comment: If $C_2 = \{1,2\}$, then $\sigma(C_2)$ doesn't make sense: a $\sigma$-algebra, or any set that is going to generate one, needs to be a set of subsets of $X$.  $1$ and $2$ are elements of $X$, not subsets of it.  It's possible you meant $C_2 = \{\{1,2\}\}$ or $C_2 = \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ but which?